# Accessing Sharepoint Resources using OAuth via Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, oauth

I am familiar with OAuth but am unfamiliar with how the APIs for Microsoft Work. They have a lot of unorganized documentation that really isn't helping me understand what to do. I want to access Sharepoint files using a Python script. I want to use a client_id and a client_secret to obtain an access token for a particular sharepoint site and access resources there. What is the best way to do this? Are there any official microsoft APIs/Documentation that make this process easy?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below. The code from here: [get-sharepoint-access-token.py](https://gist.github.com/demelziraptor/9039435)

```
import cherrypy
import jwt
import urllib.parse, urllib.request
import json

SPSECRET = 'gpYucHkODHOv6JxZJ89Kihl9ncTiTrUCAbOaF1N6uJE='

cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 3005,
                        'server.ssl_module': 'builtin',
                        'server.ssl_certificate': 'cert.pem',
                        'server.ssl_private_key': 'privkey.pem'})

class GetAccessToken(object):
    def index(self, **kwargs):
        cl = cherrypy.request.body.params
        spapptoken = cl['SPAppToken']
        decodedtoken = jwt.decode(spapptoken, SPSECRET, verify=False)

        url = json.loads(decodedtoken['appctx'])['SecurityTokenServiceUri']
        values = {
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'client_id': decodedtoken['aud'].split('/')[0],
            'client_secret': SPSECRET,
            'refresh_token': decodedtoken['refreshtoken'],
            'resource': decodedtoken['appctxsender'].split('@')[0] + '/' + decodedtoken['aud'].split('/')[1].split('@')[0] + '@' + decodedtoken['appctxsender'].split('@')[1]
        }
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
        binarydata = data.encode('ascii')
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, binarydata)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        page = response.read()

        return repr(page)

    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(GetAccessToken())
```

Or we can use [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/bbf9fb2ebfd0a77b830364f17bf0f21721885f8f/office365/runtime/auth/acs_token_provider.py#L7) to access SharePoint.